# How does one obtain data that has been returned from a method? (Java)

Tags: return

This might be a really stupid question but what happens to data that is returned from a method? For example, if I have a method that adds two numbers and I tell it to return the sum, how would I access that information from the place where the method was called?

Comment: I think you might get better answer for "What happens after death?". Specify language, environment etc for a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'll make sure to do that if I ask any other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your question is related with java.

You could assign the whole method to a new variable.

```java
public class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            int value1=2;
            int value2=5;
            int sum=sum(value1,value2);
            System.out.println("The sum is :"+ sum);
        }

        public static int sum(int value1,int value2){
            return value1+value2;   
        }
 }
```

What is actually happening, is that the method signature sum(value1,value2) holds the result of the 2 numbers summation. There is also another way of writing the code inside the method but the result will be the same.

For example:

```java
public class Test {
         public static void main(String args[]){
            int sum=sum(2,5);
            System.out.println("The sum is :"+ sum);
         }

         public static int sum(int value1,int value2){
               int sum=value1+value2;               
               return sum;  
         }
}
```

P.S. You could try to use the above samples directly. They will compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, you access the result of a function by putting the function call on the right hand side of an assignment expression.

For example, in Python, you can assign the result of calling the built-in `len` function on a list to a variable called `x` by doing the following:

```
x = len([1, 2, 3])
```